# how to get(or trigger) change event when input[checkbox or radio buttons] is changed using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, onchange

i have follwing setup, when i check/uncheck the checkbox by clicking on label or checkbox itself, the change event triggered,

but when I try to check/uncheck the checkbox using javascript say by clciking a button, the checkbox will check or uncheck but change event not triggering.

please checke the below code

```js
var checkbox=document.getElementById("check");
  
checkbox.addEventListener("change",function(){window.alert("change event")})

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
  checkbox.checked ? checkbox.checked=false : checkbox.checked=true;
})
```

```html
<label><input type=checkbox id=check>this is label</label><br>
<button>toggle checkbox</button>
```

Why is this? and how to get change event when changed using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why that ternary condition? Just use `checkbox.click();` as simple as that. It will toggle the check/uncheck together with triggering the `change` event.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("check");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
  window.alert("change event")
})

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkbox.click();
})
```

```html
<label><input type=checkbox id=check>this is label</label><br>
<button>toggle checkbox</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine. but why change event not triggering when changed with 
checkbox.checked=true;

Comment: @KaleemNalband create a jsfiddle for that and link here

Comment: @KaleemNalband you are not using the code I have above. See this http://jsfiddle.net/nj16pafL/3/ it works

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal your code works fine. but why change event not triggering by my code, my code also changing the state of checkbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180266/discussion-between-kaleem-nalband-and-ankit-agarwal).

Comment: Setting checkbox.checked manually does not trigger the "change" event, it only changes the value of the attribute. checkbox.click() however, works the same as clicking the box in the browser and thus triggers the "change" event.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could separate your logic into another function and then trigger the function both on "change" for the checkbox and "click" for the button.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("check");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
  yourFunction()
});

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkbox.checked ? checkbox.checked = false : checkbox.checked = true;
  yourFunction()
});

function yourFunction() {
  window.alert("change event")
}
```

Does that not solve your issue? I do believe [Ankit Agarwal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386758/2203828) aligns better to your original intent though.